# oracle - sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables

table A has

```
id, ans_id, ans_value
1    12     social test
2    15     math test
3    14     English test
```

Table B has

```
id, quest_id, question_value
3    10        ELA
4    11        history
5    12        math counts
```

I know that 
question id 10 from table B is equal to ans_id 14 in table A
question id 11 from table B is equal to ans_id  12 in table A
question id 12 from table B is equal to ans_id 15 in table A

so my output result should display

```
quest_id  quest_value  ans_id, ans_value
10         ELA         14      English Test
11         History     12      Social Test
12         Math Counts 15      Math Test
```

Please help me with the sql.
thanks

Comment: I don't see a way to join these two tables.  Is there any other information you have which might help here?

Comment: **I know** is too general, and we call **fixed code** aka **bad**. You should have a logic to `link` aka `join` two tables.

Comment: Your computer has to *know* that too.

Comment: no common field between two.

Comment: "question id 10 is equal to ans_id 14" makes no sense - how are they "equal"? Do you mean "corresponds to"? And, you are missing a table, the one that tells us which question_id corresponds to which answer_id.

Answer (score 3):

Your current schema is lacking information relating the two tables.  In the absence of this, you could create a bridge table, say `tablec`, which links the questions in `tableb` to the answers in `tablea`, e.g.

```
quest_id | ans_id
10       | 14
11       | 12
12       | 15
```

Then you could join as follows:

```
SELECT t1.quest_id,
       t1.question_value AS quest_value,
       t3.ans_id,
       t3.ans_value
FROM tableb t1
INNER JOIN tablec t2
    ON t1.quest_id = t2.quest_id
INNER JOIN tablea t3
    ON t2.ans_id = t3.ans_id
```

Comment: @dnoeth - more likely, "ask the OP about the bridge table".